# Google-hangout

Tags: javascript

Google Hangput APIについてご教示ください。

お年寄りにも利用できるようにボタンをクリックすると、決まった人にHangoutコールするようにしたいのですが
Google　APIを利用して可能なのでしょうか？

どなたかご存知であれば、お願いいたします。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございました。２クリック必要ですね。
ワンクリックでできたらいいのに・・・と思ってました。

Answer (score 1):

Google+ Hangout buttonを使うと、かんたんに実装できます。

ボタンのパラメータに用意されている`invites`を使うと、以下のいずれかの形式で特定のユーザー（複数可）をハングアウトに招待できます。

- Google+プロフィールID
- Google+サークルID
- メールアドレス
- 電話番号

あくまで招待ですので、ボタンをクリックしたのち、表示されるダイアログで「招待」ボタンをクリックしてもらう必要はありますが、ほぼ目的は達成できそうです。

参考：
https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button#inviting_people_to_the_hangout

例えば、メールアドレスで招待するJavaScriptコード例は、以下の通りです。

```
gapi.hangout.render("ボタンをレンダリングしたいID", {
    render: "createhangout"
    invites: [{
        id : "招待したいメールアドレス"
        invite_type : "EMAIL"
    }]
})
```